# Paperjs event delta value delayed? Path scale

Tags: canvas, paperjs

[Example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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)

So I've been trying to make **Transform** functionality for drawn paths (just like photoshop).
Atm with only **Left** and **Right** (X-axis).

Now I'm trying to figure out how to make so Transform Box continue resizing even if the mouse is on other side. So from this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekvxT.gif to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvU32.gif

The problem is when I try to **Transform** and do quick motions through the center, the points start to go  **off** . That is because of **event.delta** and **invert** statement happening.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvU32.gif

```
         if(groupDots.children['rightCenter'].position.getDistance(event.point) > groupDots.children['leftCenter'].position.getDistance(event.point)){
                var as =  -(ccc+cccy)/2
         }else{var as =  (ccc+cccy)/2}
```

I assume canvas doesn't refresh quickly enough for the smooth transition between the if statements?
At this point I'm looking for any suggestions :/

**Any help is appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis sounds right.
I think that instead of applying the transformation on the original path on every frame (and this way introducing a small offset every time), you should keep a hidden copy of the original path and compute the transformed one from it on every frame, until the mouse is released.
This way, the mouse position will stay as close as possible from the transformation handle.

Let me know if this is clear enough.

---

#### Edit

In order to precise my idea, here is a simplified [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating it.
By seeing your code, I think that you should be able to transpose it to your own use case.

```js
let shape = new Path.RegularPolygon({
    center: view.center,
    sides: 3,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange'
});
shape.rotate(-30);

const handle = new Path.Circle({
    center: shape.bounds.rightCenter,
    radius: 10,
    fillColor: 'blue'
});

let originalShape;

handle.onMouseDown = () => {
    originalShape = shape.clone().set({ visible: false });
};
handle.onMouseDrag = (event) => {
    handle.position.x = event.point.x;
    const center = originalShape.bounds.center;
    const originalVector = originalShape.bounds.rightCenter - center;
    const newVector = handle.position - center;
    const scaleX = newVector.x / originalVector.x;
    shape.remove();
    shape = originalShape.clone().set({ visible: true }).scale(scaleX, 1);
};
handle.onMouseUp = () => {
    originalShape.remove();
    handle.position = shape.bounds.rightCenter;
};
```

Comment: Don't exactly understand the order of transformation. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I added an example, let me know if this is clearer.

Comment: Great! Now just gotta fiddle around to make this work with angles, thanks for the help!